# postresql installed locally and use pgadmin with docker ; can't connect to my local database

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I'm leaning docker and i have some issues.
I have installed postrgesql on my computer (ubuntu), really installed, not with docker.
it was a classic installation

I also installed pgadmin, and everyting is fine.

Now that i want to learn docker, i decided to install pgadmin with docker and connect to my postresql server which installed locally on my machine? I did not uninstall pgadmin which was locally installed.

To laucnh pgadmin with docker,i have this command:

**`docker run -p 5050:80 e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@example.com' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=test123' -d dpage/pgadmin4`**

then i went to y browser and entered:

**localhost:5050**

pgadmin was launched in my brower, but i entered my crendentials given in docker;

Then i want to connect to my database, i gave the regular information:

```
**home address = localhost
port = 5432,
maintnance databatse = postgres
usermane = postgres**
```

password = *******

But i have a message which said it can't connect
do I have to use 2 containers, one for pgadmin and one for pg?

Comment: Did you try using the IP instead of localhost, When you're running pgAdmin inside a Docker container, localhost inside the container refers to the container itself, not your host machine where PostgreSQL is installed. You need to use the IP address of your host machine instead of localhost when connecting from within the Docker container.

Comment: And about using two containers its not necessary.

Comment: If you want to use both as containers you can refer to this site https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-run-postgresql-and-pgadmin-using-docker/
It mentioned every step in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `localhost` to `172.17.0.1` on Linux (Your case)

OBS: In some cases that will not be the default IP for `Docker` containers, so if that doesn't work, check your `Docker` IP using the following command:

```
ip -4 addr show scope global docker0
```

Change `localhost` to `host.docker.internal` on Windows and MacOS